# Pointer address Arithmetic and Hex/Dec Conversion

Tags: c, linux, hex, decimal, pointer-arithmetic

I have a pointer address I obtained from the `extern char etext`, `end` and `edata`. I also obtained address of variables using `&<Variable Name>`. Both are hexadecimal pointer addresses.

I need to do arithmetic on those addresses in decimal. How do I do so? I need to convert the address into an int in decimal so I can find size of memory segments by subtracting addresses.

Comment: I think you may be confused about what "hexadecimal" means. Numbers cannot be decimal or hexadecimal. Only string representations of numbers can be.

Answer (score 3):

Math is math.  It doesn't matter what base you do it on.    The computer is working only in base 2 anyway. Only during input or output does base matter.  Bytewise arithmetic on pointers is possible if you interpret them as `char *` pointers:

```
ptrdiff_t segmentSize = (char *)segmentEndAddress - (char *)segmentStartAddress;

printf("Segment size in base 10: %td\n", segmentSize);
printf("Segment size in base 16: %tx\n", segmentSize);
printf("Segment size in base  8: %to\n", segmentSize);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do arithmetic with pointers. Only be aware that the "unit" is not 1 but the size of the pointed object. So if p is a pointer to integer the difference in addresses between p+1 and p could be 4 bytes or more.

If you want to do arithmetic with addresses you should use pointers to char or convert them to such pointers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "hexadecimal variables", rather variables that you can print in some representation. Moreover, the standard does not guarantee that an `int` can hold a pointer object. If you use C99 or C11, it is possible to use the optional type `(u)intptr_t` to do this.

```
uintptr_t n = (uintptr_t)(void *)etext;
```

Comment: That's what `uintptr_t` is for.

Comment: However, the standard `<stdint.h>` has `intptr_t` which are guaranteed to fit pointers.

Comment: That initialization needs a cast.

Comment: @CarlNorum: A cast to `uintptr_t`?

Comment: Yes - conversions from pointer to integer types require an explicit cast.  Your example should probably be:  `uintptr_t n = (uintptr_t)&etext;`.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Since an `uintptr_t`-typed  variable can be converted only to and from `void*`, isn't the cast to `void*` necessary?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't put it there.  I put a complete example in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

> Both are hexadecimal pointer addresses...I need to do arithmetic on
>   those addresses in decimal. How do I do so?

Decimal and hexadecimal are just representations... ways to display the number. But whether I write 10 or 0xA, they're still the same number. A pointer is a number, and you can represent that number in decimal or hexadecimal, but it's still just a number. So, you can do something like:

```
char *foo = "A dog and a cat";
int offset = 4;
char fifthChar = *(foo + offset);
```

Basically, you're adding 4 to the pointer `foo` and dereferencing the result, so that `fifthChar` will hold the character 'g'.

Comment: Actually, sixth char (' ' before and)... C starts arrays at zero.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Good catch -- changed the offset so that you really do get the 5th character now. ;-)